# How to extract only text using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this html code and I am trying to extract only the content like '0004', 'March 2020', '$300,950', etc.

```
   <ul class="plan-info-lst">
    <li>
    <span>Homesite</span>
                            0004
                        </li>
    <li>
    <span>Est. availability</span>
                                March 2020
                            </li>
    <li>
    <span>Priced From</span>
                        $300,950
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="openEstimatedPaymentModal">Est. payment</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Home Size</span>
                            2161 sq.ft.
                        </li>
    <li>
    <span>Stories</span>
                            2
                        </li>
    <li>
    <span>Beds</span>
                            3
                        </li>
    <li>
    <span>Baths</span>
                            2.5
                        </li>
    <li>
    <span>Garage</span>
                            2
                        </li>
    </ul>
```

I tried using this technique, but with that I am also getting other text like 'Homesite', 'Est. availability', etc. Is there a way I could get only the other content?

```
gettext = soup_level2.find('ul', {'class' : "plan-info-lst"}).get_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lis = doc.selects('ul.plan-info-lst>li')
for li in lis:
    # print (li.span.text)
    print (li.span.nextText())
```

Result:

```
0004
March 2020
$300,950
2161 sq.ft.
2
3
2.5
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html?#module-re)! You can use it to match patterns in your string. In your case, all your data happens right after a `</span>` tag followed by a newline and indentation. So if we match that pattern like so:

```py
import re
your_data=[] # Initialize the list so we can access it outside scope of with
with open('your_file.html','r') as f:
    your_code = f.read()
    your_data = re.findall('</span>\n +(.+)',your_code)

print(your_data)
```

we can get the output `['0004', 'March 2020', '$300,950', '2161 sq.ft.', '2', '3', '2.5', '2']`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little inelegant, but can be done without regex (which is not recommended for html):

First add:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString
```

Then

```
for i in gettext.find_all('li'):
    if i.text:
        targets = i.children
        for target in targets:
            if isinstance(target, NavigableString) and len(target.strip())>0:
                print(target.strip())
```

Output:

```
0004
March 2020
$300,950
2161 sq.ft.
2
3
2.5
2
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all your help!! I found a very simple and easy solution:

```
contents=[]
a=soup_level2.find('ul',  class_ ='plan-info-lst')
for names in a.find_all('li'):
    contents.append(names.span.next_sibling.strip())
```